# SinonJS calledOnce or callCount issue for a inner object function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, sinon

Running tests with SinonJS 3 I'm facing the following issue

What's wrong with the test?

```
var creator = (function() {

  var createIfNotExists = function createIfNotExists() {
    _doCreate();
  };

  var _doCreate = function _doCreate() {
    console.log('_doCreate was called');
  };

  return {
    createIfNotExists:createIfNotExists,
    _doCreate:_doCreate
  };
}());

var util = {
  createIfNotExists:creator.createIfNotExists,
  _doCreate:creator._doCreate
};

var spyRequester = sinon.spy(util, '_doCreate');
util.createIfNotExists();

console.log(spyRequester.callCount); // prints 0 (should be
```

The line `console.log(spyRequester.callCount);` 
should print 1 but it prints 0

https://codepen.io/thiagoh/pen/XaxBjr?editors=1011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current `createIfNotExists` implementation is calling `_doCreate` that was captured in its scope. If you want it to run your mock you should somehow make the "link" between this functions dynamic. In your specific case using `this._doCreate` should work. But it would make your `createIfNotExists` to fail if called with incorrect context.

```js
var creator = (function() {

  var createIfNotExists = function createIfNotExists() {
    // pick _doCreate from the context or use default.
    (this._doCreate || _doCreate)();
  };

  var _doCreate = function _doCreate() {
    console.log('_doCreate was called');
  };

  return {
    createIfNotExists:createIfNotExists,
    _doCreate:_doCreate
  };
}());

var util = {
  createIfNotExists:creator.createIfNotExists,
  _doCreate:creator._doCreate
};

var spyRequester = sinon.spy(util, '_doCreate');
util.createIfNotExists();

console.log(spyRequester.callCount); // prints 1
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sinon@3.2.1/pkg/sinon-3.2.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey @yuri, I had figured out that this would work.. The question is, how come SinonJS can't see that this function is being called by my outside function? Isn't SinonJS able to spy closure/private functions? I would like to understand why?

Comment: " Isn't SinonJS able to spy closure/private functions?" It can't. Private functions captured in closures are trully private. Unless the author provided a way to access them they are unreachable for the outer code. If you want to spy on private functions you need something more advanced (that inspects and modifies source code). For example [rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire)

Comment: I totally understand the reasons for that, but I have made it public as you can see in the return object `_doCreate: _doCreate`. So, how come SinonJS can't see it? It actually sees the function but it doesn't see the link between `createIfNotExists` and `_doCreate`

Comment: Well you have created completly new object. Made sinon spy on one of its function (ie replace initial function in this new object with a spy that records all calls). But your `createIfNotExists` still uses original function captured in the scope. It has no idea there is another object that has some `_doCreate` property that has been replaced with a spy. It is not sinon limitation but the way you have implemented `createIfNotExists` function.

Comment: Yeah.. you're right. I'd imagined the reasons were those but I couldn't accept it. I personally don't like fallback binding calls to functions such as `(this._doCreate || _doCreate)();` but I don't see other way of doing this so that Sinon can spy my object properly..

Comment: @thiagoh Take a look at `rewire` module it works well w/o forcing you to make all the internals public.Also you might want to rethink your approach to tests and do not unit-test private stuff. Because usually it doesn't make sense. Why would you need to test `createIfNotExists` calls some inner function? Why does it matter to test it? What if you simply inline this code into the function itself? MB you really want to test it returns the same object on subsequent calls?

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.. I was aware of rewire but this tests run on a phantonJS instance (and unfortunately I cannot change this). Regarding the *private testing questioning*: it's not actually a test on the private function, I'm testing whether `createIfNotExists` is calling once and only once the private function; as you see, `creatIfNotExists` is the one that's being tested for real.